# C# should I close the streams when im using "using"?

Tags: c#, service, stream, using

I have a service running on a server that zip files and I notice that each day the memory consumed increases, when I deployed it on the server it was consuming 3.6Mb, today, 3 months later it was consuming 180Mb.

This is part of the code that I'm using:

```
for (i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(@dir + zipToUpdate) && new FileInfo(@dir + zipToUpdate).Length < 104857600)
        {
            using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@dir + zipToUpdate, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false))
                {

                    if (File.GetCreationTime(@dir + files.ElementAt(i)).AddHours(FileAge) < DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        ZipArchiveEntry fileEntry = archive.CreateEntry(files.ElementAt(i));
                        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileEntry.Open()))
                        {
                            using (FileStream sr = new FileStream(@dir + files.ElementAt(i), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                            {
                                byte[] block = new byte[32768];
                                int bytesRead = 0;
                                while ((bytesRead = sr.Read(block, 0, block.Length)) > 0)
                                {
                                    writer.Write(block, 0, bytesRead);
                                    block = new byte[32768];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        File.Delete(@dir + files.ElementAt(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            createZip(files.GetRange(i, files.Count-i), dir + "\\", getZipName(dir, zipToUpdate));
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        rootlog.Error(string.Format("Erro Run - updateZip: {0}", ex.Message));
    }
}
```

The creation of the zip or the update are similar so there is no point in paste both codes.

I do a recursive call of this for the folders inside and the service runs once each hour.

So, my question is if all these streams is what is making my memory usage increase month after month or if it can be something else.

Comment: If your using a using it auto closes once the loop is exited

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.. that's why I don't know why the memory is increasing... there could be any memory leak in this piece of code?

Comment: btw, if your `using(var foo=woo)` statment contains only another `using`, you can omit the brackets for much tidier code.

Comment: @JoãoSilva How do you measure "memory increasing"?

Comment: @spender task manager, march it started with 3.6mbs, May was already on 100Mbs

Comment: tip: there's no need to keep allocating `block`; the point here is to *reuse* the same buffer over and over - that will definitely hurt allocations, especially LOH. Just remove that second `block = new byte[32768];`

Comment: @JoãoSilva Rather than attempting to guess where a memory leak is (potentially) happening, run your program through a memory profiler. My guess is that GC is just being lazy, but without proper measurement, I'm guessing and you're guessing.

Comment: @MarcGravell yeah, true. I did it to prevent writing bytes from previous block, didn't even remember that I'm just writing the readed bytes. Thank you.

Comment: @spender I have never used it but I will take a look on it, thank you!

Comment: You need to track more to identify if it's certainly because of memory leaking...for example, if your service run once daily, the memory consuming should increase an constantly amount each day...in this case 1.76mb/day for example...if not, you should think about some other reasons

Comment: @NhonDinh It runs once each hour... I though it could be GC but the size was already quite huge to be the CG... I'm going to follow spender suggestion and get a memory profiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `using` statement takes care of closing the `IDisposable` object that it opens. This is not the source of the potential memory leak you're observing.